# Content blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

When I try to access the application in SharePoint 2013 I get an error message:

> Content blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate.

I have tried to put the site in trusted sites but without result and also clear ssl certificate, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

From this blog: Fix: [Content Was Blocked Because It Was Not Signed By a Valid Security Certificate](https://appuals.com/fix-content-was-blocked-because-it-was-not-signed-by-a-valid-security-certificate/)

1.Prevent IE from checking for certificate revocation.

2.Resetting the security settings of IE.

3.Resolving the Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager with IE conflict (if applicable).

And here is a similar issue: [Error: Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/error-content-was-blocked-because-it-was-not/7528770d-0031-49ea-a61f-201b1958eb15)